# drupal 6 and nodequeue_nodes

Tags: drupal

I'm migrating a drupal web portal from old release(5.22) to a new release(6.17).
I've some problem with nodequeue module: d6 version of this module has not the nodequeue_nodes function...
How can I substitute this function?
Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Michele

Comment: More important than the version of drupal will be the version of nodequeue you are using in each?

Answer (score 0):

....I've replaced nodequeue_nodes with nodequeue_view_nodes and it works!